# Automatic synchronization via rsync

Tags: synchronization, rsync

I need to keep my code synchronized with the same code on virtual machine. Is there a way to monitor file changes and automatically call rsync or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a shell script that would call `inotifywait` then `rsync` in a loop, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCAL="/path/to/local/dir"
RSYNC_OPTIONS=...
while true
do
    inotifywait -r $LOCAL
    rsync $RSYNC_OPTIONS
done
```

inotifywait is part of the inotify-tools package under Ubuntu