# How to invoke and terminate all background looping scripts from C program in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, synchronization, rsync

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, so I apologize for any bad questions.

I am making a C program that syncs multiple folders to remote destinations. I am planning to invoke this script from the C program: [Automatic synchronization via rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165259/automatic-synchronization-via-rsync).

The script only works for 1 directory, so I will have to have many instances to cover each directory. Therefore, I want to *run the scripts in the background* instead of terminals popping up everywhere.

Then there's also the problem of how do I *kill all the background scripts that are endlessly looping* when user decides to stop synchronization.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `killall <scriptname>`

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try using killall. I'll mark this as answered if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `pkill` or `killall` first :

```
$ pkill <script name>
# or ...
$ killall <script name>
```

If you want to force the kill of your process list :

```
$ ps -ef|awk '($0 ~ "<processname>"){print $2}'|while read -r; do kill -9 $REPLY; done
```

The column number of the PID (2 in my example) may change, depending on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "how do you kill processes from C?" If so, the answer is to use the `kill()` function. You can send any signal, but `SIG_KILL` is the default used by the command line version of `kill`.